# Move an overlay Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, overlay, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm basically trying to move an overlay along a path as time moves along. This is how I'm doing it right now:

Imagine that this is all in an NSTimer with new values for position each time.

```
circle.position =  (some moved position)

[overlay remove];
overlay = [smallMap addGroundOverlayWithOptions:circle];
```

And it basically works but introduces some flickering sometimes, which makes sense because one overlay is being deleted and a new one is added. Is there a function to actually change the position of an overlay without having to remove the old one and add a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/overlays) it says:

> If you wish to make modifications to an overlay after you've added it
>   to the map, ensure that you assign the overlay to an
>   id object when it is added.

So could you save the return value of `addGroundOverlayWithOptions`, and then update its `position` property later, instead of removing and adding the overlay again?

I haven't tried this, but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Wow, I really can't believe I never tried to edit overlay.position directly... SO simple! Works perfectly, thanks!